# npm publish on a private server throw error "UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE". But I can curl through SSL the server

Tags: ssl, npm

FYI my certificate is trusted by GeoTrust SSL CA.

I do the following command :

`npm adduser --registry https://npm.****.fr` and the error thrown is `UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE`.

I did a lot of test to fix it.

1. I try with curl and fix the issue by adding my website CRT on system (`/usr/share/ca-certificates/extra/***.crt` then `dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates`). The same error occured on NPM.
2. I try to specify option `ca`, `cafile`, `cert`, nothing change.
3. If I provide the option `strictssl=false`, it works but I don't really like this option...

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue, following command did the trick:

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
export NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
```

Answer (score 1):

I fix it by adding the CA certificate to my server.

Indeed it's the CA certificate missing, not the website certificate. But it is strange that GeoTrust SSL CA is not provide with `apt-get install ca-certificates`.